# Is $d((a_n),(b_n))=\sum 2^{-n}\lvert a_n-b_n\rvert$ a complete metric on $l^{\infty}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $l^{\infty}$ be the space of all bounded, complex sequences and consider the metric $$d((a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty},(b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\lvert a_n-b_n\rvert$$
on it. I'm trying to figure out whether this $d$ makes $l^{\infty}$ complete or not.

Let $(x_k)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $l^{\infty}$ where $k=0,1,2\ldots$ and let us denote the $n$th term of $x_k$ by $a^{(k)}_n$. Then it is easy to see that for each fixed $n$, the sequence $$a^{(1)}_n,a^{(2)}_n,a^{(3)}_n,\ldots$$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and hence converges to $c_n\in\mathbb{C}$, say.

We must now show that $c=(c_n)$ is a bounded sequence and that $(x_k)$ converges to $c$ in $d$-metric, but I'm not sure how to this. Is there a universal bound, $M$, bounding $a^{(k)}_n$ for all $n$ and all $k$? If that is the case, then I think I can finish the proof, but what if there is no such a bound? Please help me figure this out.

Comment: No such bound. Take your favourite not-too-fast-growing unbounded sequence and look for a sequence in $\ell^{\infty}$ that converges pointwise to it. If you're not exceptionally unlucky, it will be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $l^\infty$ is not complete with that metric.

Let $a_n^{(k)}=\min(n,k)$, so
$$x_1 = (1,1,1,1,\ldots)$$
$$x_2 = (1,2,2,2,\ldots)$$
$$x_3 = (1,2,3,3,\ldots)$$
The sequence $(x_k)$ is Cauchy because for $i<j$,
\begin{align}
d(x_i,x_j)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}|\min(i,k)-\min(j,k)| \\
&=\sum_{k=i}^j 2^{-k}(k-i) + \sum_{k=j+1}^\infty 2^{-k}(j-i) \\
&=2^{1-i}-2^{1-j}\\
&<2^{1-i}
\end{align}
But if $x$ is in $l^\infty$ with bound $M$, then $d(x,x_n)>2^{-n}$ whenever $n>M$.  So $x$ is not a limit for the $x_n$, the $(x_n)$ have no limit in $l^\infty$, and $l^\infty$ is not complete with this metric.

The obvious (pointwise) limit is $(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$, but that is not in $l^\infty$.